# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm running this:

```
def add (a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract (a, b):
   print "SUBSTRACTING %d - %d" %(a, b)
   return a -b

def multiply (a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def devide (a, b):
    print "DEVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b

print " lets do some math with just function!"


age = add(30, 5)
hight = subtract (78, 4)
weight = multiply (90, 2)
iq = divide = (100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Hight: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, hight, weight, iq)
```

I'm getting this:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple
```

but why?

Comment: o my god Sorry I just found out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some typo in your code:

```
iq = divide = (100, 2)

def devide (a, b):
```

need to become

```
iq = divide(100, 2)

def divide (a, b):
```

Comment: You should also change divide to devide ;)

Comment: Or the other way around, and change `hight` to `height` as well